# WebStorm highlights Karma/Jasmine testing keywords as deprecated

Tags: webstorm, karma-jasmine

I'm working with Ionic2 and want to run unit tests so I set up Karma and Jasmine. Unfortunately WebStorm puts a line through all my jasmine keywords like `describe`, `it`, `expect` etc.

How can I disable this behavior? Why does WebStorm do this?

Comment: What version of Karma/Jasmine are you using?  Typically webstorm picks this up from the typings file and marks anything the developers marked as deprecated as such.

Comment: "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",

Comment: So from what I can dig up, there's not much you can do about this.  Karma is bundled with the IDE, but it's using an older version of Karma.  So the Karma devs made a change for backwards compatibility, but put in deprecation messages about everything.  It seems like you will have to live with the deprecation messages until Webstorm updates to the newer version or the unbundle Karma

Comment: Can I update karma, and karma-jasmine to newer versions to prevent this?

Comment: No because it's the libraries that are bundled with Webstorm that are actually causing the problem. The IDE defaults to these versions when doing it's syntax highlighting.  It shouldn't affect the functionality, it's just there as a warning to you that the feature you are using will be going away in a future version (and according to the Karma GitHub, it's  going to be in the next version)

Comment: What version of WebStorm you have?

Comment: Not reproduced for me. In my case "describe" is not resolved (thus, it's marked with weak warning "Unresolved function or method describe()").
If it's marked as deprecated for you, then I guess it should be possible to navigate to "describe" function declaration (using Ctrl+B or Meta+B).
Where is it navigated to? Is the function declaration marked as deprecated indeed?

Do you have typings directory?

BTW, WebStorm doesn't bundle Karma, however, it does bundle karma-intellij plugin that communicates with karma.